# how to use ".bak" file

Tags: backup, data-recovery, data-loss

I want to know how to use a backup file.

My friend changed some configuration in interface file but those setting doesn't work but the previous setting works.

He create a backup file `interfaces.bak` but I don't know how to use this`.bak` to restore my old `interface` file ?

Answer (score 5):

> ".bak" is a filename extension commonly used to signify a backup copy of a file. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bak_file)

---

To restore this backup file :

1. Delete the `interface` file  with the broken settings.
2. Remove `.bak` of the `interfaces.bak` file.

Comment: To make it even clearer for everyone, .bak is only an additional extension to the name to "rename" it. as soon as the .bak is removed, the file will function as before - Btw good answer @hg8

Comment: Please explain to me, why should I restart my system?

Comment: As I am not sure witch file he is talking about I think the best way to take change in account for a beginner is to reboot the system. I edited my answer if someone came across this question in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to give an example, perhaps this will make you clear :

Lets say I have a program `foobar` that depends on the configuration file `/etc/foobar/interfaces`. I have taken a backup of it as `/home/me/foobar/interfaces.bak`.

Then I have made some changes to `interfaces` file and it is not looking good now. So I want to replace my current `interfaces` file with the original one I have backed up at `/home/me/foobar/interfaces.bak`.

To do so all I need is:

```
cp /home/me/foobar/interfaces.bak /etc/foobar/interfaces
```

If you want you can make a backup of the current `interfaces` file too:

```
cp /etc/foobar/interfaces /home/me/foobar/interfaces.current
```